# Swift iOS auto adjust height for UILabel for UITableViewCell()

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uilabel

How do I make it auto resize the height of each cell based on the length of textLabel? Ideally I would like textLabel to be wrapped as well, so the textLabel can take however many lines it needs. Below codes are what I have currently:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let notification = self.fetchedTweetsArray[indexPath.row]

        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = notification
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: are you using autolayout ?

Comment: not using autolayout

Answer (score 0):

First of all your cellForRowAtIndex should be like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
     let cell : CustomCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ID_CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)  as! CustomCell

cell.selectionStyle =  UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

cell.lblData.text = "CustomCell....."
return cell

}
```

No of lines for UILabel should be zero.

[image]

Now as per height of UILabel you have to calculate dynamic height for each cell and keep it in mutable array so later on you can use in heightForRowAtIndex.

Make sure auto resizing like this on UILabel

[image]

Just made a sample code, you can download and observe.

[Download sample code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKRUVBR0JkZ3R0NU0/view?usp=sharing)